# How to create a \newenvironment in latex for a scaled table

Tags: latex

I try to define a table as a new environment.

```
\newenvironment{scaledtable}[1]{%
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rcrrrrrrrrrrrrcc}
}{
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}}
```

The problem I have is that I can't use scalebox{}. If I put the closing bracket into the end definition of the environment, latex can't assign the brackets anymore. I also can not use PStricks because of pdflatex.

Comment: I don't get the problem. What is it you're trying to achieve? Why can't you use `scalebox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`\lrbox`](http://web.mit.edu/kolya/.f/root/net.mit.edu/sipb.mit.edu/project/tex-new/doc/latex/base/usrguide/node19.html) to temporarily store the table, then scale it

```
\newsavebox{\scaledtablebox}
\newcommand*{\scaledtablefactor}{1}
\newenvironment{scaledtable}[1]{%
\renewcommand*{\scaledtablefactor}{#1}%
\begin{table}[h]%
\caption{xxx}%
\label{tab:xxx}%
%
\begin{lrbox}{\scaledtablebox}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}%
}{%
\hline%
\end{tabular}%
\end{lrbox}%
%
\begin{center}%
\scalebox{\scaledtablefactor}{\usebox{\scaledtablebox}}%
\end{center}%
\end{table}%
}
```

Works like this (`0.5` is the scale factor):

```
\begin{scaledtable}{0.5}
Hello & World! \\
\end{scaledtable}
```